# How to style div the same as h1?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have website - my Polish blog and I have one difference between home page and article page, h1 on home page and div on article, and div is broken on mobile (size 360px width, same in desktop dev tools)

**Article**

```
<div class="h"><a href="...">Głównie JavaScript</a></div>
```

[image]

at https://jcubic.pl/2020/02/powiadomiena-push-notifications.html

and

**Home Page**

```
<h1 class="h"><a href="...">Głównie JavaScript</a></h1>
```

[image]

https://jcubic.pl

everything is the same, I've even copied `h1` CSS styles from user-agent css to `.h` into my file.

I've tried to include [normalize.css](https://unpkg.com/normalize.css) with no effect. I need to use div becasue of SEO h1 should be article title and on home page (and index pages) it can blog title.

Why I'm not able to set div the same style as h1, what's the difference between h1 and div is there some browser quirk and you can't make them look the same?

**EDIT**:

The problem have nothing to do with anything except the tag, I've just replaced the tag on article page, just to be sure if other code don't interfere with the header, and it work same as on index page. So the problem is h1.

I think that I'll just create new css for the header when element is div, but still I would like to know why it's not the same, is this Chrome Bug?

Comment: try css `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: @MisterJojo it need to wrap into two lines for smaler size, the problem is that there is space between before, a and after when element is div and with h1 there are no space.

Comment: could you provide an example code for this part, because I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: @MisterJojo It will be hard to do, there is lot of code. Maybe the issue is only on Linux I use Fedora.

Comment: The CSS is different. With the Inspector I can see that the p has `text-size-adjust` and `line-height`, while the h1 does not. You might look into those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but the solution is to use `p` tag that works the same as h1. If you know why create an answer.